# XML - relative path to XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have simple Spring project splitted in three modules, like:

- module1

  - src/main/java/com/test/Module1Test.xml
- module2

  - src/main/java/com/test/Module2Test.xml
  - src/main/java/com/test/Modules.xsd
- module3

  - src/main/java/com/test/Module3Test.xml

Like you can see in module2 I have create XSD file to validate XML files in all three modules.
To validate XML file with XSD in module2, I simply added following line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Module2Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Modules.xsd">
```

However I have no idea how I can validate `Module1Test.xml` and `Module3Test.xml` files with my XSD. I cannot use absolute path to my XSD in XML files like:

```
<Module2Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:\\project\\module2\\src\\main\\java\\com\\test\\Modules.xsd">
```

and I would like to use relative path, something like:

```
<Module2Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="project\\module2\\src\\main\\java\\com\\test\\Modules.xsd">
```

Or in other better way, just to not use **absolute** path.

Do you know if it's possible? How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/project/module2/src/main/java/com/test/Modules.xsd"`?

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to use relative path with fulll file path to XSD file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "**that really depends**", depends on how you are coding and way you are referencing, so I would highlight both the approaches:

## Approach #1: Pass as direct stream

You can pass the XSD directly as an input stream to your program, so that you need not to depend upon the "noNamespaceSchemaLocation" attribute even when you have no namespaces for elements in your XML document.

Below is a sample program:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document; 
import org.xml.sax.SAXException; 
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
import org.xml.sax.InputSource; 


import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.StringReader; 


import javax.xml.XMLConstants; 
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder; 
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory; 
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException; 
import javax.xml.transform.Source; 

import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource; 
import javax.xml.validation.Schema; 
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory; 
import javax.xml.validation.Validator; 

public class XmlSchemaValidationHelper { 

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        XmlSchemaValidationHelper schemaValidationHelper = new XmlSchemaValidationHelper();
        schemaValidationHelper.validateAgainstSchema(new File(argv[0]), new File(argv[1]));
    }

    public void validateAgainstSchema(File xmlFile, File xsdFile) { 
        try {
            System.out.println("### Starting...");
            // parse an XML document into a DOM tree 
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
            builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
            DocumentBuilder parser = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
            Document document = parser.parse(xmlFile); 

            // create a SchemaFactory capable of understanding WXS schemas 
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 

            // load a WXS schema, represented by a Schema instance 
            Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(xsdFile); 
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile); 

            // create a Validator instance, which can be used to validate an 
            // instance document 
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator(); 

            // validate the DOM tree 
            validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
            System.out.println("### Finished...");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { 
            throw new OpenClinicaSystemException("File was not found", ex.getCause()); 
        } catch (IOException ioe) { 
            throw new OpenClinicaSystemException("IO Exception", ioe.getCause()); 
        } catch (SAXParseException spe) { 
            spe.printStackTrace(); 
            throw new OpenClinicaSystemException("Line : " + spe.getLineNumber() + " - " + spe.getMessage(), spe.getCause()); 
        } catch (SAXException e) { 
            throw new OpenClinicaSystemException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause()); 
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) { 
            throw new OpenClinicaSystemException(pce.getMessage(), pce.getCause()); 
        } 
    } 

    public class OpenClinicaSystemException extends RuntimeException { 
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String errorCode; 
        private Object[] errorParams; 

        public OpenClinicaSystemException(String code, String message) { 
            this(message); 
            this.errorCode = code; 
        } 

        public OpenClinicaSystemException(String code, String message, Throwable cause) { 
            this(message, cause); 
            this.errorCode = code; 
        } 

        public OpenClinicaSystemException(String message, Throwable cause) { 
            super(message, cause); 
        } 

        public OpenClinicaSystemException(Throwable cause) { 
            super(cause); 
        } 

        public OpenClinicaSystemException(String message) { 
            super(message); 
            this.errorCode = message; 
        } 

        public OpenClinicaSystemException(String code, Object[] errorParams) { 
            this.errorCode = code; 
            this.errorParams = errorParams; 
        } 

        public OpenClinicaSystemException(String code, Object[] errorParams, String message) { 
            this(message); 
            this.errorCode = code; 
            this.errorParams = errorParams; 
        } 

        public String getErrorCode() { 
            return errorCode; 
        } 

        public Object[] getErrorParams() { 
            return errorParams; 
        } 

        public void setErrorParams(Object[] errorParams) { 
            this.errorParams = errorParams; 
        } 
    }

}
```

Run it like this: `E:\xmlValidator>java XmlSchemaValidationHelper po.xml test/po.xsd` and you do not need to depend upon the "noNamespaceSchemaLocation" attribute because you are directly passing the XSD as an input stream to your validator/parser.

**This is the quick and dirty way to validate XMLs against XSD**.

## Approach #2: Escape the XSD path properly

You just need to escape your XSD path correctly, so use either of below instead:

```
<Module2Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C://project//module2//src//main//java//com//test//Modules.xsd">
```

OR

```
<Module2Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C://project//module2//src//main//java//com//test//Modules.xsd">
```

Read [MSDN official article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757863(v=vs.85).aspx) about same.

---

## Final words: Use XML namespaces and targetNamespace

I would recommend that **you should use XML namespace and targetNamespace** for properly relating the XML instances with XML schema. Consider below sample XSD and XML.

For anyone who doesn't understand the concepts of XML namespaces and targetNamespace, I hope below quick points would be helpful:

- In the XSD, you need to define the "targetNamespace" like this `targetNamespace="http://www.books.org"` which is nothing but you are defining the namespace for your actual XML instance. And this same namespace i.e. `http://www.books.org` you need to use in your XML instance.
- In the XML instance, you need to:

  - Make the  "targetNamespace" from the XSD as the default namespace like this `xmlns="http://www.books.org"`
  - And then use "schemaLocation" attribute to tell the XML validator that what should be the target namespace in the XML schema, and validator will derefence the URI's appropriately `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.books.org"`

**Sample XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BookStore xmlns="http://www.books.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.books.org">
        <Book>
                <Title>My Life and Times</Title>
                <Author>Paul McCartney</Author>
                <Date>1998</Date>
                <ISBN>1-56592-235-2</ISBN>
                <Publisher>McMillin Publishing</Publisher>
        </Book>
        <Book>
                <Title>Illusions The Adventures of a Reluctant Messiah</Title>
                <Author>Richard Bach</Author>
                <Date>1977</Date>
                <ISBN>0-440-34319-4</ISBN>
                <Publisher>Dell Publishing Co.</Publisher>
        </Book>
        <Book>
                <Title>The First and Last Freedom</Title>
                <Author>J. Krishnamurti</Author>
                <Date>1954</Date>
                <ISBN>0-06-064831-7</ISBN>
                <Publisher>Harper &amp; Row</Publisher>
        </Book>
</BookStore>
```

**Sample XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.books.org"
            xmlns="http://www.books.org"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:simpleType name="ISBN-type">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="\d{1}-\d{5}-\d{3}-\d{1}|\d{1}-\d{3}-\d{5}-\d{1}|\d{1}-\d{2}-\d{6}-\d{1}"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:element name="BookStore">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Book" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Author" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:gYear"/>
                            <xsd:element name="ISBN" type="ISBN-type"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Publisher" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```